# Prove/refute: Every tautology is contingent

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I'm asking to prove/refute the following statement:

> Every tautology is contingent.

According to definition of contingent:

> *A statement that is neither self-contradictory nor tautological is called a contingent statement. A contingent statement is true for some truth-value assignments to its statement letters and false for others.* [Source.](http://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/)

Can I tell that the statement is not correct by definition or should I use a more formal way to refute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as "tautology" and "contingent statement" are meta-language definitions (they cannot be expressed in the logical system itself; we're talking *about* the system) there isn't really a more "formal" way to do it.

You can *expand* your claim by specifying *why* a tautology cannot be contingent "by definition", but this won't add to the formality. You can do that if you want practice writing proofs (explaining your conclusions in words) but otherwise I see no added value.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the claim would be **true** if there were no tautologies.

So the most convincing way to refute it would be to show a concrete statement that is a tautology and (therefore!) not contingent.